# Fire function on change of <input> tag with jQuery (checkbox/textbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, onchange

I'm looking to fire an updateTotals() function whenever input tags are changed on my form (checkboxes, textboxes).

I'm using Telerik MVC NumericTextBoxes/PercentTextBoxes which ultimately render as  tags just like my checkboxes.

I've attempted to apply something like this to my page to do so:

```
$("#SupervisionRequired").change(updateTotals());
```

This jQuery fires on the initial page load, but doesn't fire when the Checkbox is changed.

Since I'm using some generic MVC Helpers based on my model (EditorFor, TextBoxFor) I cannot directly apply the onChange event onto these controls. My end goal is to have the updateTotals() function called when a Checkbox is checked/unchecked, and when the user clicks outside of an input tag (for the NumericTextBoxes).

What can I do to change my above jQuery, or add to it to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `updateTotals()` function inside a `function(){}`.

```
$("#SupervisionRequired").change(function(){
    updateTotals()
});
```

Currently, you're immediately *calling* function `updateTotals()`, and passing the return value as an event listener to the `change` event.

Instead of adding the `change` event to `$("#SupervisionRequired")`, you an use a selector to select all of your input elements inside your form, eg: `$("#myFormName input").change(function(){updateTotals();})`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I'm glad I posted this right away before tinkering too overly long with syntax!

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is

```
$("#SupervisionRequired").change(updateTotals);
```

(without the `()` after `updateTotals`)